# Will my program execute "else" even if it executed my "if"?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm wondering, if I have the following code:

```
v=5;
if (v==5){
   v++;
}
else{
   //do something else
}
```

will my program "execute" the else part since my variable `v` is now different from `5`?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: yeah I should have probably done that thanks anyways

Comment: Yeah thank you :)  I'l make sure to do that

Comment: No, it will only check, or "evaluate" the condition `v==5` once and from there decide which of the two parts to execute, the if part or the else part. It's always one of them, never both.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it will not execute the else statement if the if condition is satisfied

Answer (score -3):

In this case:

```
v=5;
if (v==5){
v++;
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

But if you add for loop:

```
v=5;
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
if (v==5){
v++;
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

It will reach insufficient condition and get in to your else statement